# jQuery not working while using loop in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working on script to submit values into db with the help of jquery.
Without using loop in this code, the script work's fine

PHP:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="<?php echo 'rid' ?>" value="<?php echo $roww['id']; ?>">
```

But when I use loop, the jquery did not work and likewise the values did not insert into db.
I'm expecting all values to save into db in a single row.
But its now working
[image: DB where values save]

[image: form interface to submit]

View:

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url('start'), array('id' => 'login_form')); ?>
<?php $i=0; $queryw = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM plans');
    foreach ($queryw->result_array() as $roww) { 
?>
<div style="float:left; width:40px; margin-left:10px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="<?php echo 'rid'.$i ?>" value="<?php echo $roww['id']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<?php $i++; } ?>
<div class="error" id="logerror"></div> 
<button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login_form').validate();   
    $(document).on('click','#btn-login',function(){
        var url = "<?php echo site_url('start/user_login');?>";       
            if($('#login_form').valid()){
                $('#logerror').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>themes/images/btn-ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $("#login_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data==1) 
                        setTimeout('window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('welcome/profile'); ?>"; ',4000);
                        else  $('#logerror').html('Error: some values are missing.');
                        $('#logerror').addClass("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function index() 
{
    $this->template->loadContent("game/start.php");
}

public function user_login()
{
    if($_POST['rid'.$i] == TRUE) :
        $datas = array(
            'code' => $_POST['rid'.$i]
            );
        $this->db->insert('pin', $datas);
            echo 1;
    else :
        echo 0;
    endif;          
}
```

Comment: 1. Do any error messages show up? Either in the developer console or from php. 2. Have you checked your php error logs?  3. `$i` appears to be undefined in your Controller. Is something missing due to a copy-paste error?

Comment: 1. Error fshowed from Jquery is **Error: some values are missing.** 2. no php error log 3/ `$i` was defined as `$i = 0;`

Comment: 1. Error fshowed from Jquery is **Error: some values are missing.** 2. no php error log 3.  `$i` was defined as `$i = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think your function user_login() is having problem. The problem is $i. How can user_login() know what is $i or what value it have in it. $i is never send to user_login() from your ajax code. Surely there will be no PHP error, though your answer always be '0' i.e 'Error: some values are missing.' in your case.

Solution for your case will be:
1. send $i value from your ajax code to user_login(). You do this by sending hidden input value for $i in your form OR you may use other alternative ways.

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url('start'), array('id' => 'login_form')); ?>
<?php $i=0; $queryw = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM plans');
foreach ($queryw->result_array() as $roww) { 
?>
<div style="float:left; width:40px; margin-left:10px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="<?php echo 'rid'.$i ?>" value="<?php echo $roww['id']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<?php $i++; } ?>

// added line
<input type="hidden" name="loop_val" value="<?=$i;?>" />

<div class="error" id="logerror"></div> 
<button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

2. So, Now your function will be something like this:

   ```
   public function user_login()
   {
       $j = 0; // for checking true values
       for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['loop_val'];$i++) {
           if($_POST['rid'.$i] == TRUE) {
               $datas = array(
                   'code' => $_POST['rid'.$i]
               );
               $this->db->insert('pin', $datas);
               $j++;
           }
       }
       if($j != 0) {
           echo 1;
       } else {
          echo 0;
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I appreciate your effort. The problem wasn't solve, from your correction the code started inserting in db and JS still show me error `echo 0;` . Also it did not insert into the db how I expected... i want all values to be in one row in pin dbTable, not creating different rows. Thanks

Comment: Here is Update Code: public function user_login()
    {
        $j = 0; // for checking true values
        $combine = ''; // combining variable for all POST 'rid'
        for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['loop_val'];$i++) {
            $combine = ($combine*10)+$_POST['rid'.$i]; // combining all 'rid' POST values in one
            $j++;
        }
        if($j > 0) {
            $data['code'] = $combine;
            $this->db->insert('pin', $data);
            echo 1;
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    }

Comment: Wow... You are guru, but I discovered that all the values inserted end with `0` in db. where is the `0` coming from. also after inserted successfully, Ajax still not redirecting but show error. Thanks

Comment: for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['loop_val'];$i++) OR for($i=0;$i<$_POST['loop_val'];$i++) should solve insertion of value with '0'.  For your Ajax code after success : if(data==1) {
                                            setTimeout(window.location.href = "<?=base_url().'welcome/profile'?>", 4000);
                                        } else {
                                            $('#logerror').html('Error: some values are missing.');
                                            $('#logerror').addClass("error");
                                        }

Comment: Also you may have to add "die;" OR "exit;" after "echo 1;" and "echo 0;" in user_login()

Comment: Is there any way I can include letters in the input. I try to use letters such as: R 6 Y G. but the db shows 0600